# Copy an element of a table row

Tags: javascript, html

I think this will almost do what I want it to with some changes.  What I need to do is copy this row and paste it into another text area.  I tried .copy(); but that didnt work.  Could someone point out what I need to do to make it function?  Thanks

```
// Find and remove selected table rows
$(".delete-row").click(function(){
    $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

did you have tried `.clone()`?

```js
$(".delete-row").click(function(){
    $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).parents("tr").clone().prependTo('someElement');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So my entire table row is like this:  Peter Parker   peter.parker@gmail.com.  I really want to change the delete row.click  to a copy to clipboard of just the email address so it can be pasted into the sender on an email and also pasted into a text area to keep track of who was sent emails insted of looking through the "sent" folder in gmail.

Comment: did you mean copy the innerText element to clipboard? use ```navigator.cilpboard.writeText()```

Comment: Thank you for the help. What line would it replace?  Not very good at this but I was given this to make it work.

Comment: /**$(function() {
  $('.copy-to-clipboard input').click(function() {
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $(".copied").text("Copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(2500);
  });
});**/
$(function() {
  $('.copy-cell').click(function() {
    const other = $(this).next('td')
    other.find('input').focus();
    other.find('input').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    /*$(".copied").text("Copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(2500);*/
  });
});